# Validate Stored Procedure Success in Powerapps

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, powerapps

I am fairly new to powerapps, but it sounds like there is a major limitation on being able to return values for a SQL Server stored procedure.

I have an app that when you push a button pulls data from various controls on screen and submits it to a stored procedure. This is done by invoking a flow. The code is basically :

```
EditPuddles.Run(ActionDrop.Selected.Value, PuddlesText.Text,
                ClassicDrop.Selected.Value, ServiceRates.Text, User().FullName)
```

The code works and does what it is supposed to. However, what I need now more than anything is it to tell me when it fails or succeeds.

Ideally I would have it return  a values that I could use to determine if I should display a success or failure message. I get that I cannot return a data set, but it must at least be able to tell if there is an error.

Comment: Check out the "Configure Run After" option in Flow. Execute a PowerApps Response, email, etc. to notify you when the app fails and / or succeeds. https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/error-handling/

Comment: I did see that but, I need much more robust error handling, for example what error?

Answer (score 2):

I'm also new to PowerApps and Power Automate but I figured out a way to show results on success and an error message on failure, after a flow is executed.

### PowerApps

For your example the code for the property "OnSelect" of the button should be:

```
UpdateContext({ PuddlesResult: EditPuddles.Run("a", "b", "c") });
If(
   Not IsBlank(PuddlesResult.errormessage), 
   // on failure:
   Notify(PuddlesResult.errormessage, NotificationType.Error, 5000),
   // on success: (use PuddlesResult.ResultSets.Table1)
   Notify("All good", NotificationType.Information, 5000)
)
```

### Power Automate

Your flow in Power Automate should look like this:
[image: Power Automate picture]

#### Capture the error message

On error the action "Execute stored procedure (V2)" returns output:
[image: Output sproc]

To return the message in the output update the action "Respond to a PowerApp or flow":

- Text: ErrorMessage
- Expression: `outputs('Execute_stored_procedure_(V2)')?['body']?['message']`

#### Return the error message only on failure/timeouts

Select "Configure run after" on the action "Respond to PowerApp or flow":
[image: Configure fun after picture]

And set it to only run this action on failure and time outs:
[image: Run after failure or timeouts picture]

For returning normal results you can use action "Response" and set the "Configure run after" settings to "Is successful".

I hope this helps you and others as it took me a long time too to figure this out. But it will allow you to handle succes and failure appropriately in your PowerApp.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but lost that job partially due to not figuring this out :).

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that man... Hope you find something else.